# Swing - Creating a tinted transparent foreground while making the background items not clickable

Tags: java, swing

So I'm creating a Java Application User Interface using Swing. Basically, whenever a process is being completed, I want to have an Overlay that's somewhat transparent with a certain tint, and in the foreground a loading gif would be displayed. The background items will be not clickable to prevent any other processes being loaded/run at once. The only part I really need help with is making the tinted background and making the items in the background not clickable. Ideally, I want this class to be used as a Util class to be used in other case where I would need to start a loading screen. So far, this is my code:

```
package com.cervinakuy.game;

import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Overlay extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Overlay() {

        setUndecorated(true);
        setBackground(new Color(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0.5f));
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        getRootPane().putClientProperty("apple.awt.draggableWindowBackground", false);

        setVisible(true);
        pack();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you are doing except you would use a `modal JDialog` instead of a JFrame. A modal dialog prevents events from being passed to the parent JFrame until the dialog is closed.

Another approach is to use a `Glass Pane`. The glass pane can cover the frame. You can then intercept the Mouse/Key events to prevent further processing until the glass pane is removed.

Check out [Disabled Glass Pane](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/07/disabled-glass-pane/) for an example of this approach.

Comment: Could you link me to where you learned how to use a Modal JDialog? I have never used one and would love to learn how.

Comment: @Espin, Did you try the API? The API contains a link to the Swing tutorial. There are examples for all Swing components in the tutorial.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean, API? Tutorial? I'm not following.

Comment: The API is what you use to find all the classes and all the methods of the classes. When you read the API it has a quick description of what the class does. When you read the JDialog API you will also find a link to the Swing tutorial which has more detailed information and code examples.

Comment: Oh okay, I think I get what you mean, I'll try this. Thanks!